# Какой в данной ситуации нужен скрипт передачи и получения значения?

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. Здесь при нажатии кнопку заказать выходит дополнительное окошко. Какой можно употребить скрипт получения и передачи значения, только скрипт. Что-б в зависимости от того, куда нажал в поле ввода тариф, уже было введено слово. Например нажал на демо, вышло окошко и в поле уже введено демо, нажал на стандарт уже введено стандарт.Код с таблицей и дополнительным окошком пишу ниже:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr class="tablic">
    <td>Формат</td>
    <td>Демо<br/>0 P<br/>
      <button type="button" class="knopka_demo" data-modal="modal_1">Заказать</button>
    </td>
    <td>Стандарт<br/>3000 P<br/>
      <button type="button" class="knopka_standart" data-modal="modal_2">Заказать</button>
    </td>
    <td>Оптимальный<br/>5000 P<br/>
      <button type="button" class="knopka_Optimal" data-modal="modal_3">Заказать</button>
    </td>
    <td>Максимальный<br/>8000 P<br/>
      <button type="button" class="knopka_maksimal" data-modal="modal_4">Заказать</button>
    </td>
    <td>Максимальный плюс<br/>8000 P+<br/>
      <button type="button" class="knopka_maksimal_plus" data-modal="modal_5">Заказать</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="overlay" data-close=""></div>

<div id="modal_1" class="dlg-modal">
  <span class="closer" data-close=""></span>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="lable">Тариф</th>
        <td class="input"><input type="text" class="mytext" value="Демо"></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="lable">Контактное лицо</th>
        <td class="input"><input name="name" size="40" maxlength="40" class="input" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="lable">Название организации</th>
        <td class="input"><input name="name" size="40" maxlength="40" class="input" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="lable">ИНН организации</th>
        <td class="input"><input name="name" size="40" maxlength="40" class="input" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="lable">Email</th>
        <td class="input"><input name="email" size="40" maxlength="40" class="input" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="lable">Телефон</th>
        <td class="input"><input name="phone" size="40" maxlength="40" class="input" type="text"></td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td align="center">
          <input name="order_submit" type="submit" value="Заказать"> </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("tr.tablic td button").click(function(){
  var title = $(this).closest("td").find(".title").text();
  $("#modal_1 .price-type input").val(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="tablic">
    <td>Формат</td>
    <td><span class="title">Демо</span><br/>0 P<br/>
      <button type="button" class="knopka_demo" data-modal="modal_1">Заказать</button>
    </td>
    <td><span class="title">Стандарт</span><br/>3000 P<br/>
      <button type="button" class="knopka_standart" data-modal="modal_2">Заказать</button>
    </td>
    <td><span class="title">Оптимальный</span><br/>5000 P<br/>
      <button type="button" class="knopka_Optimal" data-modal="modal_3">Заказать</button>
    </td>
    <td><span class="title">Максимальный</span><br/>8000 P<br/>
      <button type="button" class="knopka_maksimal" data-modal="modal_4">Заказать</button>
    </td>
    <td><span class="title">Максимальный плюс</span><br/>8000 P+<br/>
      <button type="button" class="knopka_maksimal_plus" data-modal="modal_5">Заказать</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="overlay" data-close=""></div>

<div id="modal_1" class="dlg-modal">
  <span class="closer" data-close=""></span>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="lable">Тариф</th>
        <td class="input price-type"><input type="text" class="mytext" value="Демо"></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="lable">Контактное лицо</th>
        <td class="input"><input name="name" size="40" maxlength="40" class="input" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="lable">Название организации</th>
        <td class="input"><input name="name" size="40" maxlength="40" class="input" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="lable">ИНН организации</th>
        <td class="input"><input name="name" size="40" maxlength="40" class="input" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="lable">Email</th>
        <td class="input"><input name="email" size="40" maxlength="40" class="input" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="lable">Телефон</th>
        <td class="input"><input name="phone" size="40" maxlength="40" class="input" type="text"></td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td align="center">
          <input name="order_submit" type="submit" value="Заказать"> </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня почему то не получается, что может быть не так? Могу показать полностью весь код, у меня также прописан css и js, на всплывающее окно при нажатии кнопки. Вот это окошко дополнительное(строки тариф, контактное лицо...) что под таблицей находится в сыром виде, оно скрыто и появляется при нажатии. Может на это влиять что у меня не получается?

Comment: @Stanislav Нет, то что окно скрыто, влиять не будет, если оно является частью (хоть и скрытой) документа страницы. Вы заметили, что я завернул заголовки в шапке таблицы в `<span class="title">` и добавил `class="input price-type"` к ячейке с названием тарифа в модальном окне?

Comment: Это да, заметил

Comment: Оно отвечает, за то, что-б в каждом появлялся текст от нажатия на определенную кнопку?

Comment: @Stanislav да, без этих двух вещей мой код работать не будет

Comment: Ну это я прописал также. Но срабатывает только демо и всё.

Comment: Может вам показать весь код? посмотрите, где мож ошибка.

Comment: Здесь работает, если нажать выполнить код работает, а проверял брал чисто ваш код отдельно написал, почему то не работает.

Comment: ну в любом случае спасибо, будем разбираться, направление хоть ясно теперь

Comment: @Stanislav Попробуйте сделать пример в вопросе, используя кнопку "Фрагмент кода" в редакторе вопроса.

Comment: Разобрался все получилось, спасибо

Comment: @Stanislav Пожалуйста. Успехов!